# How to transition between two UIView's using a custom UIViewController without memory leaks?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to simulate turning book pages using views.  Each UIView displayes two pages (left and right) when looking onto an open book.  As a page is turned a new UIView should be displayed.  My current approach is to have a custom UIViewController with a blank root UIView and have the pages be subviews.  As I add a new subview I transition from the last subview added to the new one.  Once the transition is complete I want to remove the previous last subview because it is no longer needed -- it is no longer visible and takes up memory.

In essence, it's this:

```
UIView * myOldPageView = [[self.view subviews] lastObject];
[self.view addSubview:myNewPageView];
// ... transition between the two views
[myOldPageView removeFromSuperview];
```

Here is my initial stab at it which fails with a mysterious crash with no stack trace.  This method is in my custom UIViewController:

```
-(void) switchToController:(UIViewController *) controller {
    [controller viewWillAppear:YES];        

    if (self.currentScreenController != nil) {
        [self.currentScreenController viewWillDisappear:YES];
    }

    [self.view addSubview:[controller view]];

    if (self.currentScreenController != nil) {
        [[self.currentScreenController view] removeFromSuperview];
        [self.currentScreenController viewDidDisappear:YES];
    }

    self.currentScreenController = controller;

    [controller viewDidAppear:YES];
}
```

Doing a `[controller release]` after this method call causes the crash, which is strange as the retain count is greater than 0.  If I don't do a release I get a memory leak.

[Edit]
Here's another approach without using a controller, that crashes when the old page view is removed from its superview:

```
-(void) switchToView:(UIView *) screen {
  [self.view addSubview:screen];
  [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:screen cache:NO];
  [UIView commitAnimations];
  if (3 < [[self.view subviews] count]) {
    [[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview]; // <- crash
  }
}
```

[Edit]  Even if I try to remove the new subview immediately after adding it I get crash, with no transition animations:

```
 -(void) switchToView:(UIView *) screen {
   [self.view addSubview:screen];
   if (3 < [[self.view subviews] count]) {
     [screen removeFromSuperview]; // <- crash
    }
  }
```

[Edit]  I now strongly believe the issue is in deallocating the added view, which means it has nothing to do with animations or view controllers.

Comment: [myOldPageView removeFromSuperview]; is also available

Comment: Have you turned on NSZombieEnabled just in case?

Comment: @Nick I did with no results.  I am beginning to think that there is an internal conflict of common view ownership between the two controllers -- only one controller can own a view, and here both the root and the argument controller will own the same view.  Still though I require a solution.

Comment: Can you point out some more why you have to switch to a different UIViewController? You mentioned first that each page is a UIView, I am a bit confused right now.

Comment: did you consider creating a xib with a main view and two additional subviews?

Comment: @Nick You're right in that I don't need to -- this was my original approach and I thought I have to use controllers in order to have an animatable transition.  I reimplemented without the need of a controller (see above), but I still get a crash when I try to remove the old page view from its superview after animation completes.

Comment: @Thomas No.  I have about 30 views to display and prefer to create the views programmatically.

Comment: Try to add a beginAnimations:context to complete animation. Does the console yield a more descriptive error message now?

Comment: @Nick Animations have nothing to do with the problem it seems.  I get a crash if I don't use animations as well.  The crash happens when removing a subview from the root view controller's view, see above.

Comment: Can you remove the view after some delay using performSelector and moving the removal code it's own method?

Comment: how about using a uINavigationController and playing with setViewControllers, manipulating the order of the two controllers within the array?

Comment: @Nick The issue was somewhere else, this code works now.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Thomas The issue was somewhere else, thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice, then please enlighten us, what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at the UIView method `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:`

Using the `options:` you can specify the page curl effect.

From the docs: Discussion
This method is a simple way to transition from the view in the fromView parameter to the view in the toView parameter. By default, the view in fromView is replaced in the view hierarchy by the view in toView. If both views are already part of your view hierarchy, you can include the UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews option in the options parameter to hide or show them.

Comment: I'm aiming for iOS before 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Try removeFromSuperview of the view you'd like to dispose.

Comment: You're right, but I wrote the question wrong, it's now corrected.  The original problem follows.  I'm trying to figure out if there is an alternate approach to trying to accomplish this from what I do.

Answer (score 0):

This is just from the docs, but here we go: Use a [NavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and manipulate the array in

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
```

where the last item added to the array becomes the top item of the navigation stack. From the docs:

> If animations are enabled, this method
>   decides which type of transition to
>   perform based on whether the last item
>   in the items array is already in the
>   navigation stack. If the view
>   controller is currently in the stack,
>   but is not the topmost item, this
>   method uses a pop transition; if it is
>   the topmost item, no transition is
>   performed. If the view controller is
>   not on the stack, this method uses a
>   push transition. Only one transition
>   is performed, but when that transition
>   finishes, the entire contents of the
>   stack are replaced with the new view
>   controllers. For example, if
>   controllers A, B, and C are on the
>   stack and you set controllers D, A,
>   and B, this method uses a pop
>   transition and the resulting stack
>   contains the controllers D, A, and B.

i.e. if you have view controllers A an B, create arrays

{A, B}
{B, A}
{A}
{B}.

and lets say you start with page one being A. Then you want a push transition to B, set the array to be {B}, note that:

> If the view controller is not on the
>   stack, this method uses a push
>   transition.

Next time, set it to {A} and so on for iteration in the forward direction.
Now if you want a pop transition from B to A, note that

> If the view controller is currently in
>   the stack, but is not the topmost
>   item, this method uses a pop
>   transition;

you set it to {B, A} and visa versa from A to B. Then of course after animations(?), just return to the {A} and {B} arrays to get back to the starting point - if the view controller is already the topmost, no transition is performed. Good luck;)